# Pandas dataframe what is the best way to deal with selecting rows and then modyfinng a column without SettingwithCopyWarning

Tags: pandas

I have a large dataFrame object and I would like to first select some rows and then then convert the timestamp column:

```
def choose_loc(data, lat, lon, lat_diff, lon_diff):

    data = data.loc[(data.lat > (lat - lat_diff)) & (data.lat < (lat + lat_diff)) & (data.lon > (lon - lon_diff)) & (data.lon < (lon + lon_diff))]

    return data


column_names = np.genfromtxt(header_path, dtype=str, delimiter='\t')
dtypes = {"lat": np.float64, "lon": np.float64, "timeStamp": np.int64}
pos_lat = 0.0
pos_lon = 0.0
size_lat = 0.05
size_lon = 0.05

data = pd.read_csv(filePath, sep='\t', dtype=dtypes, header=None, names=column_names, error_bad_lines=False)

data = choose_loc(data, pos_lat, pos_lon, size_lat / 2, size_lon / 2)

data.loc[:, 'timeStamp'] =  pd.to_datetime(data.loc[:, 'timeStamp'], unit='ms')
```

When I run the above code I get SettingwithCopyWarning on the last line. I don't really understand why, as I use .loc and nothing should be copied. I can make it work by running `data = choose_loc(data, ...).copy()`, but the file is large and I would like to avoid copying to save time and memory. So what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data = data.loc[(data.lat > (lat - lat_diff)) & (data.lat < (lat + lat_diff)) & (data.lon > (lon - lon_diff)) & (data.lon < (lon + lon_diff))].copy()
```

Comment: But I am copying data this way and I don't need the previous data, I just want to work on a slice.